# Python Multiprocessing fails when running in docker container

Tags: python, docker, multiprocessing

I created a container to run some of the Python scripts for my pipeline.
When running the scripts locally everything goes as expected but when I run the script using the container `Manager()` from multiprocessing gives the following error:

```py
Process SyncManager-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/multiprocessing/process.py", line 314, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 592, in _run_server
    server = cls._Server(registry, address, authkey, serializer)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 156, in __init__
    self.listener = Listener(address=address, backlog=16)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 447, in __init__
    self._listener = SocketListener(address, family, backlog)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 590, in __init__
    self._socket.bind(address)
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/source/ReferenceMatrix.py", line 113, in <module>
    with Manager() as manager:
         ^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/multiprocessing/context.py", line 57, in Manager
    m.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 567, in start
    self._address = reader.recv()
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 249, in recv
    buf = self._recv_bytes()
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 413, in _recv_bytes
    buf = self._recv(4)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 382, in _recv
    raise EOFError
EOFError
```

Both the container and local are running with Python 3.11.0 (in the docker file `FROM python:3.11.0-slim`).

I have added

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
  with Manager() as manager:
    ...
```

to the code but the error persists.

*Edit:*

The docker file is as follows:

```
# Build Preprocessing into clustered files 
## Base image
FROM python:3.11.0-slim

## Aquire date/time of build
ARG buildDate

## Retrive the library requirements text file and the python scripts for preprocessing of both references and samples
COPY requirements.txt /tmp/
ADD CreateRefMeta.py /source/
ADD SamplesMatrix.py /source/
ADD ReferenceMatrix.py /source/
ADD FormatSample.py /source/
ADD ClusterFilteringRef.py /source/
ADD support_functions.py /source/

################# METADATA #################
# Image information
LABEL about.image="Python base image with required libraries for MethAtlas"
LABEL image.authors="Maisa ------ Santos"
LABEL image.authors.email="-----@-----"
## Update when new python and libraries versions are available
LABEL image.maintainer="Maisa ----- Santos"
LABEL image.maintainer.email="-----@-----"
LABEL base_image="python:3.11.0-slim"
LABEL base_image.added_libraries="numpy==1.24.3, pandas==2.0.2, scipy==1.10.1, matplotlib==3.7.1, PyYAML==6.0"
LABEL base_image.other_software="bedtools==2.30"
LABEL image.version="1.0"
## Date/time of build
LABEL buildDate=${buildDate}
# Software information
LABEL software="MethAtlas for DNA methylation deconvolution"
LABEL software.version="No info available"
LABEL about.article="https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-018-07466-6"
LABEL about.documentation="https://github.com/nloyfer/meth_atlas"
#LABEL about.license_file=""
#LABEL about.license=""
LABEL about.tags="Epigenomics,DNA methylation,Sequencing,Deconvolution"
# Docker command examples for running from this image
LABEL docker.run01.help="docker run --rm mferrosantos/preprocessing:1.0 /source/CreateRefMeta.py -h"
LABEL docker.run02.help="docker run --rm mferrosantos/preprocessing:1.0 /source/SamplesMatrix.py -h"
LABEL docker.run03.help="docker run --rm mferrosantos/preprocessing:1.0 /source/ReferenceMatrix.py -h"
LABEL docker.run04.help="docker run --rm mferrosantos/preprocessing:1.0 /source/FormatSample.py -h"
LABEL docker.run05.help="docker run --rm mferrosantos/preprocessing:1.0 /source/ClusterFilteringRef.py -h"
LABEL docker.run1.referenceList="docker run --rm -v path-to-data-directory:/mnt -it mferrosantos/preprocessing:1.0 /source/CreateRefMeta.py /mnt/config.yaml -o /mnt"
LABEL docker.run2.sampleMatrix="docker run --rm -v path-to-data-directory:/mnt -it mferrosantos/preprocessing:1.0 /source/SamplesMatrix.py /mnt/samples_path /mnt/path-to-clusterFile [-exp] [-cpg] -gen genomeVersion [-metaS] -o /mnt"
LABEL docker.run3.referenceMatrix="docker run --rm -v path-to-data-directory:/mnt -it mferrosantos/preprocessing:1.0 /source/ReferenceMatrix.py /mnt/path-to-RefMeta -gen genomeVersion -re /mnt/path-to-the-resource-folder -o /mnt"
LABEL docker.run4.formatSamples="docker run --rm -v path-to-data-directory:/mnt -it mferrosantos/preprocessing:1.0 /source/FormatSample.py /mnt/path-to-sampleMatrix -o /mnt"
LABEL docker.run5.clusterFilterRefs="docker run --rm -v path-to-data-directory:/mnt -it mferrosantos/preprocessing:1.0 /source/ClusterFilteringRef.py /mnt/path-to-refMatrix [-DMR DMRmethod] [-cluster DMRclusterFile] -it iterations -col refCollapse [-ex [exclude1 exclude2 ...]] -cF clusterFiltering [-r randomSeed] -o /mnt"

############################################

## Check for updates to the system and install them
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y\
 libcurl4-gnutls-dev \
 libssl-dev \
 libssh2-1-dev \
 libxml2-dev \
 libhdf5-dev \
 libgmp-dev \
 libpng-dev \
 libgsl-dev \
 libxt-dev \
 libcairo2-dev \
 libtiff-dev \
 fftw-dev \
 procps \
 python3-pip

## Update pip
RUN /usr/local/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip

## Install python requirements
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r /tmp/requirements.txt

## Install bedtools
RUN apt-get install bedtools

## Image uses the python3 command line as the entry point
ENTRYPOINT [ "python3" ]
```

The script in question is ReferenceMatrix.py although even if shared it would require data that I am at no liberty to provide since it relates to unpublished research. The script in question runs correctly on Mac, Linux and Windows so I suspect the problem lies on the Dockerfile. All the other scripts behave properly and output the correct results except this one which is the only one using `Manager()`.

***Solved:***

After testing many things I just changed the base image from `python:3.11.0-slim` to `python:3.11.4` and that seemed to solve the problem. The only down side is that now the image is quite bigger.

Comment: Please show more of your code, your Dockerfile, and how you're running the thing. I cannot reproduce it with the info you provided (base image and running Manager)

Comment: @h4z3 I have added the Dockerfile and some extra information. I am not sure if it will be of big help

Comment: This question would benefit from a [mcve] -- enough code that we can run it locally and reproduce the problem you're asking about.

Comment: I just prompted Chat GPT and got like 10 reasons why this could be happening. Have you tried to check for any of these? :https://chat.openai.com/share/4880e3e4-8888-4cf5-8901-199be9cf4ab1

Comment: @larsks thank you for the advice: I will try to do that next time although the problem here was not the code itself (since the scripts are all available with the image), it was the type of file required (specifically formatted compressed coverage files) and those I don't think I can share in here

Comment: @Dimitar I tested all of that and nothing was working. I ended up switching the base image and that did the trick